Difference between CredProtect and CryptProtectData. Which is better?
I was looking for ways to protect the password data in the my application. I was initially using CryptProtectData API, but I see that the Windows Credential Provider sample use CredProtectW API. What is the difference in terms of encryption and which is better?

As these articles say:
https://threathunterplaybook.com/library/windows/data_protection_api.html
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/protect-data-machine-account-microsoft-capi-kashif-mushtaq/

CryptProtectData is part of the DPAPI.
It's used to encrypt you Master key (windows user login password) and uses 3DES in early versions of windows and from windows 7 and after AES-256.

On the other hand the CredProtectW is part of CAPI. Couldn't find the algorithm it uses, but know that it has similar concept with CryptProtectData with an exception on integrity of the data (only CryptProtectData has keyed integrity check) in case of ciphertext poisoning.


if your application manages passwords like a password manager, then I would recommend to check for a simpler and less "encrypt-decrypt restrictive" library which uses ChaCha20-Poly1305 or AES-256, because if you want in the near future to make it portable, you will have problems with it.

The Microsoft docu on MS Learn, CredProtectW

Additional to the answer from @JimChr
which is very technical
A simple separation is also

CredProtectW: Will be only valid in memory of the current session. When the user logs out and in again, the value can NOT be restored

CredProtectDataW: Will be PERSIST even when user logs out and in. Only the machine scope, security context needs to be the same.


